# RavenDB Embedded license not registering

Tags: ravendb

I have added RavenDB.Embedded@5.2.2 to an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application and I am attempting to configure the license without entering it into the studio GUI form. I have 2 licenses: a community and a developer -when I copy/paste either into the studio GUI it works.

I have tried:

1. Putting the license json into a file called `license.json` in the `Server` directory
2. Setting the command line arguments to include `--License.Path=C:/path/to/the/license.json`
3. Setting the `License.Path` key in `settings.json` to the path to the license
4. Steps 2 and 3 but with `License` and the text value of the license

My expectation is that when setting the license via configuration, the studio should not prompt me for a license. Perhaps my assumption is wrong about this.

Has anyone successfully configured a RavenDB embedded instance without the web form?

Comment: I was able to achieve what I was looking for by POSTing the license to `/admin/license/activate`, but this still feels like a bit of a hack. Ideally, just having the `license.json` file in the `Server/` directory would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the RavenDB team:

> Hi,
>
> License is only automatically activated on a non-bootstrapped server (new, empty one). It can be done e.g. like that:

```
EmbeddedServer.Instance.StartServer(new ServerOptions
{ 
CommandLineArgs = new List<string>
{
"--License.Path=D:\\temp\\lic.json"
}
});
```

> But if you previously bootstrapped the server (e.g. created a database and there was no license in the env variables or command line args), then license will not be automatically activated. If this was done, then you can issue a POST to https://github.com/ravendb/... with the license JSON.

Comment: Could you please provide a URL to the source of information?

Comment: so does this mean that the configuration setting described here does not work?

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/csharp/server/configuration/license-configuration#license

Answer (score 0):

License provided in the `License.Path` is activated during database creation. I was able to activate it automatically when I created a new instance (I'm using Docker for local development) and created my first database using Studio.